# how to resolve collision response problem?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics

The collision detection im using is an AABB collision detection techniques between two squares
i cant seem to resolve this problem where the sides collision are detected and the squares are stuck along the edges and collsion occurs along the edge until the squares pass along the y-axis.i have also highlighterd the problem area     -------problem-------

How to solve this problem?
please check the link for better understanding of my problem
https://qwtfy.github.io/

```js
const canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

square1={
    h:100,
    w:100,
    dx:2,
    dy:4,
    x:0,
    y:0
}
square2={
    h:100,
    w:100,
    dx:-2,
    dy:-2,
    x:200,
    y:250
}

function drawSquare(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(square1.x,square1.y,square1.w,square1.h);
    ctx.fillStyle='#000';
    ctx.rect(square2.x,square2.y,square2.w,square2.h);
    ctx.fillStyle='#000';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function moveSquare(){
    square1.x+=square1.dx;
    square1.y+=square1.dy;
    square2.x+=square2.dx;
    square2.y+=square2.dy;

    // left right wall collision
    if(square1.x<0 || square1.x+square1.w>canvas.width)
        square1.dx*=-1;
    if(square2.x<0 || square2.x+square2.w>canvas.width)
        square2.dx*=-1;

    // top bot wall collsion 
    if(square1.y<0 || square1.y+square1.h>canvas.height)
        square1.dy*=-1;
    if(square2.y<0 || square2.y+square2.h>canvas.height)
        square2.dy*=-1;
 // -------problem-------
        // square to square collsion

        // sides
        if(square2.x<square1.x+square1.w&&square1.x<square2.x+square2.w&&(Math.abs(square1.y-square2.y)<70))
            {
                console.log('sides');
                // console.log(square1.x,square1.x+square1.w,square2.x)
                square1.dx*=-1;
                square2.dx*=-1;
            }
        else if((square2.y+square2.dy<=square1.y+square1.dy+square1.h&&square1.y+square1.dy<=square2.y+square2.dy+square2.h) && (Math.abs(square1.x-square2.x)<70))
            {
                console.log('tops');

                square1.dy*=-1;
                square2.dy*=-1;
            }

 // -------problem-------
}

function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    drawSquare();
    moveSquare();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
  
update();
```

Comment: `badStyle === bugs` is always true. Long lines mean you can not see the error. Last clause of the two sqr V sqr (`if`) statements you assume the size is 70 not 100,  If you are unconcerned with the occasional overlap and square are always same size then change last clause to  `&& Math.abs(square1.y - square2.y) < 100` same for x direction. However in `moveSquare` you are not resolving position, only  partial velocities, and you are assuming the deltas are always opposite. I can think of about a dozen edge cases where it will fail, but you may be lucky and never encounter them. Good luck

Comment: @Blindman67 appreciate the help it seems to correct my problem.could you further give an example of the edge cases which could cause problem.response would be very much appreciated